# Create a new Tag

Tags: discussion

For SharePoint 2013 apps Development in Office 365 NAPA Tool is Provided so please Why Can't we create a Tag for Napa Tool like "SharePoint 2013 Napa Tool" or "Napa Tool for Office 365".

Answer (score 1):

Done. The tag is office-365-develop-tool (cannot exced the 25 char). Anyone feel free to edit, rename, or add tag synonim (Napa would be one good candidate, as also "Second-Sayan-With-Vegeta").

Comment: +1 for the Dragon Ball reference

Comment: Are you telling me there was another reason for that name?

Comment: BTW, added a new temed hat.

Comment: Well, on the show it's Nappa, so... maybe.

Comment: Just an excuse to avoid paying copyright rights to Akira ^_^. Wait till the next release "Office 9k Karot" and you will see I was right O_o